# In blender 2.8 I want to set a keyframe_insert at a point of a bezier curve by pythonscript

Tags: python

The animation, that a sphere follows a bezier-path, works as I want. But the sphere needs exact 100 frames to do that.  How can i set keyframes that the sphere has absolved the route from frame 10 to frame 50 ?

I tried the following, but the lines are ignored:

```
obj.bezier_points[0].keyframe_insert(data_path = 'co', frame=10)
obj.bezier_points[1].keyframe_insert(data_path = 'co', frame=50)
```

and another try:

`obj.bezier_points[0].keyframe_insert(data_path="bevel_factor_start", frame=10)`

generates the error:  `"bevel_factor_start" not found.`

It would be great, if anybody has an advice for me.

Comment: I find out that  the line:   obj.data.bevel_factor_start=0                                     before the second try removes the error, but there is also no result.

Comment: `bezier_points[0]` is of type [`BezierSplinePoint`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.BezierSplinePoint.html), which does not have any attribute called `bevel_factor_start`; that's why the second attempt does not work. I don't know about the first one though.